# spring microservices swagger-ui no select a definition drop down

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc

Last time I upgraded to `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.4.3` and now I don't see `Select a definition`. [image]

Before I was using `1.2.31` version and then it looks like on the screen above.

Is there option to bring back that dropdown?

Comment: Arek Szast, i think your question is answered :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure you have defined your APIs in a group in order to enable the select a defintion drop down list:

Here the code of demo with groups. For example:

```
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi storeOpenApi() {
    String paths[] = {"/store/**"};
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("stores").pathsToMatch(paths)
            .build();
}
```

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/tree/master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc

Comment: I've got it:
`@Bean
 public List<GroupedOpenApi> apis() {
  return routeDefinitionLocator.getRouteDefinitions()
    .filter(routeDefinition -> routeDefinition.getId().matches(".*-service-docs|.*-adapter-docs"))
    .map(routeDefinition -> routeDefinition.getId().replace("-docs", ""))
    .map(serviceId -> GroupedOpenApi.builder()
      .pathsToMatch("/" + serviceId + "/**")
      .setGroup(serviceId).build())
    .collectList()
    .block();
 }`
But it's not working on newest version

Comment: Here is the link for a full working code, with spring cloud gateway:https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/blob/master/sample-springdoc-openapi-microservices/gateway-service/src/main/java/org/springdoc/demo/services/gateway/GatewayApplication.java